# display values retrieved from yii sql query

Tags: php, yii

I am using yii framework. And I want to retrive some values from a table. Here is my query-

```
$criteria = new CDbCriteria;
$criteria->addBetweenCondition('Timestamp', $sdate, $edate, 'AND');
$criteria->select = array('EID','count(EID) as EIDC','Timestamp');
$criteria->group = 'EID';
$e_info = Users::model()->findAll($criteria);
```

Now after this how do I retrieve EIDC?

I tried

```
foreach ($e_info as $info) {
    echo $info->EIDC;
}
```

But I get an error. What is the correct way of doing this?

Comment: Always post the error. It will help us understand what's the issue.

Comment: Define a property named `$EIDC` in your `Users` model, so Yii can assign the value of the `COUNT` expression to it.

Comment: @AmalMurali I did not post the error, because I thought it wasn't relevant. Because I know this is not the correct way of doing it.

Comment: @DCoder How do I do that?

Comment: Uh, `class Users extends CActiveRecord { public $EIDC; ... }` ?

Comment: Is there no other way of doing this? i do not have access to the model files.

Comment: You can try and write your own model that `extends Users` and contains this property and nothing else, then use it in the search function. If that fails, there are no other automagic ways, only through a manual query.

Comment: You mean you dont have access for your own project source files ?

Answer (score 0):

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveRecord#findAll-detail

`findAll()` returns: list of active records satisfying the specified condition. An empty array is returned if none is found.

do a `var_dump` of `$e_info` to see what's in there.

And always post the error.